# Solve $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

I wonder how to solve $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x+1}dx$$I went about solving it like this: \begin{align*}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x+1}dx& =\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin(x-1)}xdx=\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\cos(1)-\cos(x)\sin(1)}xdx\\ & =\cos(1)\left(\frac{\pi}2-\text{Si}(1)\right)-\sin(1)\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos x}xdx\end{align*}
So it remains to find how to solve $$\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos x}xdx$$Or at least write it in terms of special functions. Maybe there is a way to solve the original integral without going through this integral.

Comment: Is that not just $-\operatorname{Ci}(1)$?

Comment: How did you get $\operatorname{Si}(x)$? What is $x$? Your initial integral does not depend on $x$, it is a real number.

Comment: Btw, you can [re-write](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2614740) your integral as $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - x} }}{{1 + x^2 }}{\rm d}x} ,
$$ which has much better convergence properties for numerical calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have done is absolutely correct.
In the last step, you can write
$$-\int_{x}^\infty{\frac{\cos t}{t}\mathrm{d}t} = \operatorname{Ci}(x)$$
Where $\operatorname{Ci}(x)$ is the cosine integral of $x$.
Otherwise, you can use numerical approximations to get the answer without finding the antiderivative.

Comment: Thanks. Wolfram Mathworld simply stated that $\text{Ci}(x)=\int\frac{\cos x}x dx$ without giving bounds.

Comment: @KamalSaleh Are you referring to an entry other than the one devoted to $\operatorname{Ci}(x)$? The definite integral is listed [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) (line $(1)$)

Comment: @user170231 Oh I see, that's my fault. I found a picture on the internet and didn't bother clicking on the link.